# Reorder elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with child divs aligned by three in a row. Child div's css:

```
{position:relative,float:left}
```

I use jQuery snippet like this:

```
$("#catalog-body").find("[data-"+ type +"='" + val + "']").hide();
```

It works well, but it may cause gaps in rows(in place of hidden divs). How to make divs realign?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change your element structure. Don't use table and rows. instead of use one container div and place children divs inside it. make all children float left and set container div width to 3*child element width

Comment: Can you include in your description the HTML structure of #catalog-body?

Comment: To Nishan Senevirathna : I have absolutely the same element structure you described

Comment: check out this fiddle. The jquery and css you provided should work. http://jsfiddle.net/jg54Lb5y/.. there is probably something else breaking the behavior. Thats why we need more info.

Comment: `code`<div id="catalog-body">
                               <div class="catalog-item" data-knit="....">

    <div class="catalog-img">
       <a href="....">
        <img class="main lazyload" src="..."/> 
      </a>
    </div> 
 <div class="item-desc">
  ....
 </div>
</div>`code`
div with catalog-item class repeats many times and they have float:left

Comment: I still don't see a problem with that code. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jg54Lb5y/4/

Comment: I don't see gaps here: http://jsfiddle.net/jg54Lb5y/5/ must be something else...

Comment: Are the images and catalog-item divs the same size? Are there items with item-desc too long?

Comment: Wait, there is a `,` before `float:` in your css. That should be a `;` or float won't work! Unless it's just the example that is wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Change your element structure like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    #catalog-body{
        width : 300px;
    }

    .child-ele
    {
        float:left;
        width:90px;
        height:30px;
        border:1px red solid;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="catalog-body" >
        <div class="child-ele" >1</div>
        <div class="child-ele" >2</div>
        <div class="child-ele" >3</div>
        <div class="child-ele" >4</div>
        <div class="child-ele" style="display:none" >5</div>
        <div class="child-ele" >6</div>
        <div class="child-ele" >7</div>
        <div class="child-ele" >8</div>
        <div class="child-ele" >9</div>
        <div class="child-ele" >10</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the result you should get,
[image]

5th element is hidden but all the childrens are align properly

Comment: @Regent exactly agree with you. This is just explanation.